# use Issue.GetAllForRepository to find issues with labels

Tags: c#, octokit.net

I'm using `Octokit.net` to filter issues in a repository using the *`Issue.GetAllForRepository(owner,name,request)`*.
In the request I set the property *Since* to set the time filter and the Property `*Labels*` to filter for a set of labels: **I would like to find all the issues that have at least one of these labels, but from the results I think that are selected only the issues have all these labels.**
  Is possible to configure the request so every issue that has at least one label is found? At the moment I have to do a single request for every label.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the GitHub API itself - when specifying a list of labels in the issue search, it will return results matching **all** labels...